# What HTML tag do I need to tell BeautifulSoup to look for?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape news articles from the homepage of a site by have BeautifulSoup find each story by their link. I can get the parts of the website I need to, but I can't get my program to iterate through the links. I have gotten my code to work for another website that had a more simple HTML structure, but can't seem to get it to work for the website I actually want to scrape. The site is

the HTML of the site looks like:

```html
<li>
            <div class="grid-container">
                <div class="grid-25 mobile-grid-100">
                    <a href="https://energynow.com/2019/08/five-things-to-know-in-world-business-today-332/">

                    <img src="  https://energynow.com/wp-content/uploads/World-Business-5-400x270-1.jpg" width="400" height="auto" class="size-medium">



            </a>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-75 mobile-grid-100">
                    <div class="post-title"><a href="https://energynow.com/2019/08/five-things-to-know-in-world-business-today-332/">Five Things to Know in World Business Today</a></div>
                    <p class="post-date">August 2, 2019</p>
                    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </li>
```

and my Python code is the following:

```py
coverpage_news = soup1.find_all('li')

number_articles = 10
news_contents = []
list_links = []
list_titles = []

for n in np.arange(0, number_articles):

    if "live" in coverpage_news[n].find('a')['href']:
        continue

    # getting link of article
    link = coverpage_news[n].find('a')['href']
    list_links.append(link)
```

I'm trying to get each link so I can then scrape each story, but instead I am getting the error `TypeError: 'NoneType object is not subscriptable` when it gets to the `if 'live'` statement or (when I comment out that line) when it hits the `link = coverpage_news[n].find('a')['href']` line.

Any suggestions? Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the output of `soup1.select("li > a")`. It looks like there is at least one other `<a>` tag which does not have `href`, which happens to be before the one you are interested in. And `find` only selects the first one it finds. That CSS selector will give you a list of all `<a>` tags which are within a `<li>` tag, btw.

Comment: Alternatively, there are some `<li>` tags which do not contain any `<a>` tag...

Comment: Can you share the start url?